# Create a vendor selector in Expense claim screen

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a Field to store 'VendorID', in my own DAC.

First I tried using Acumatica attributes to show the selector, like the below

```
[VendorNonEmployeeActive(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName), CacheGlobal = true, Filterable = true)]
```

AND

```
[POVendor(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName), CacheGlobal = true, Filterable = true)]
```

AND other few attributes. but either it shows employee data or nothing. I even tried to write a selector of my own as below where BAccountRef is a class derived from BAccount.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Vendor.bAccountID,
                                    InnerJoin<BAccountRef, On<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountRef.bAccountID>>>,
                                    Where<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccountRef.status.active>,
                                    And<Vendor.type, Equal<BAccountType.vendorType>>>>), new Type[] { typeof(BAccountRef.acctCD), typeof(BAccountRef.acctName) },
                               SubstituteKey = typeof(BAccountRef.acctCD))]
```

Unfortunately no luck, from the behaviour, it seems like the records are auto filtered to show employee info. I cant figure out how this is happening. How to make the selector show vendor info? How this is auto filtering the employees in this graph?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your BQL queries towards `Vendor` DAC are translated into SQL queries to **EPEmployee** table. This behavior is caused by the `EPEmployee` cache (and therefore the `BAccount` cache) initialized prior to `Vendor` cache.

Try using `PX.Objects.AP.VendorAttribute` together with the `BAccountR` DAC - use of `BAccountR` will break inheritance between the `Vendor` and `BAccount' DACs and should be translated into SQL queries towards`BAccount`and`Vendor` tables:

```
[Vendor(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,
    Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>, 
        Or<Vendor.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>>), 
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, CacheGlobal = true, Filterable = true)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Vendor.status, IsNull, 
                        Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>, 
                        Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>),
    AP.Messages.VendorIsInStatus, typeof(Vendor.status))]
```

Comment: This assisted me to get the correct selector definition.

Comment: If you use the Vendor attribute, it still wont work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All,

@Ruslan's answer helped to get the correct definition for the selector. When we use **BAccountR** or **VendorR** DAC's the SQL is not translating to EPEmployee and hence i am able to get the correct information.

```
[PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("VENDOR", typeof(Search<VendorR.bAccountID, Where<VendorR.type, Equal<BAccountType.vendorType>,
                                        And<VendorR.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>>>>), typeof(VendorR.acctCD), new Type[] { typeof(VendorR.acctCD), typeof(VendorR.acctName) })]
```

Comment: For a Vendor selector, make sure you always use `PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(typeof(Search<VendorR.bAccountID, ...>), "VENDOR", typeof(VendorR.acctCD))` instead of the `PXSelectorAttribute`. This is very important, because vendor identifiers is a segmented key, which is not supported by PXSelector. PXSelector can handle 1 segment, but will put you into trouble once you define 2nd+ segment  for the **Vendor** segmented key.

Comment: Thanks for this info. i have updated it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my recent projects I've used the following in order to get VendorCD:

```
    #region vendor
    public abstract class vendor : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _Vendor;
    [VendorRaw(typeof(Where<Vendor.vendorClassID, Equal<Current<VendorFilter.vendorClassID>>>), 
        DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName), DisplayName = "Vendor ID")]
    [PXDefault("", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string Vendor
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Vendor;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Vendor = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Same result as i mentioned. :(

Answer (score 0):

recently I had to add a Vendor Selector on the ExpenseClaimsDetails DAC, after trying several options, this is the one that worked for me:

```
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor", Enabled = true)]       
    [PXDimensionSelector("VENDOR", typeof(Search<VendorR.bAccountID, Where<VendorR.vStatus, Equal<VendorStatus.active>>>),
        typeof(VendorR.acctCD),
        new Type[] { typeof(VendorR.acctCD), 
            typeof(VendorR.acctName), 
            typeof(VendorR.vendorClassID),
            typeof(VendorR.taxRegistrationID)},
        Filterable = true, 
        SelectorMode = PXSelectorMode.TextModeSearch,
        DescriptionField = typeof(VendorR.acctName))]
    public int? UsrEVVendorID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrEVVendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrEVVendorID> { }
```